# Overlaying a label on the navigation bar (In the way that notifications are displayed) - Swift / Xcode 7

Tags: swift

I want to be able to have a label that is the same size as the nav bar that will come down when an error occurs. For example, on the signup, if a user doesn't put in a username, I would like the label to come down and say "Please enter a username". I have everything working except I can't place the label in front of (on top of) the nav bar.

---

```
@IBAction func letsGoButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {





    if nameTextField.text == nil {


        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: { () -> Void in

            // I still need to add a delay and move the label back up and off of the screen

            self.enterNameErrorLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.enterNameErrorLabel.center.x, self.enterNameErrorLabel.center.y + 65)

        })


    } else {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nameTextField.text, forKey: "name")



    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("setupSegue", sender: self)


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you've tried?

Comment: I am trying to do this in the storyboard rather than programmatically.

Comment: Even if you do this entirely in the storyboard you'll still have to have some code like when to hide/show the new view, telling the application that it needs to add the subview to the navigation bar, etc.

Comment: You won't be able to do this in Interface Builder. This isn't a standard feature provided by the OS, so there's no support for doing this type of thing without code.

Comment: So I don't have a problem creating a label programmatically. One problem I have is how to make the label extend the full width of each devices screen. How would I set that?